# Export customers list with IP address?

Tags: export

When I was exporting my customer's list,

under **System => export=>customers**,

I'm not getting an IP address,

How can I configure?

Is this required to do a configuration from the core?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The customers don't have an IP address attribute.
The ip address is kept only on the orders placed from frontend.
And it wouldn't make sense to keep the ip address on the customer object since the customer can access your website from different locations or even from the same location that has a dynamic IP address.

Comment: Yes, customers do not have that attribute, what should I do?

Comment: But, my requirement is needed to export with an IP address? how?

Comment: you can get the orders of each customer and get the ip address from there, but this does not guarantee you get the right one.